# Which s better Distinct before or after Select?

Tags: c#, linq

**filterCollection is a list of int's**

I am trying to create a new list from an existing with distinct with Linq

In this cause which is better

```
 filterCollection.Select(filterId => new FilterTable() { FilterId = filtertId }).Distinct().ToList();
```

OR

```
 filterCollection.Distinct().Select(filterId => new FilterTable() { FilterId = filtertId }).ToList();
```

I am not sure this is correct.

Comment: This depends on your query-prvodier. Is this some database or an in-memory list?

Comment: Define "better" =) But for linq to objects usually it should be better to filter collection first (also I believe it depends on `GethHashcode` and `Equals` implementation for `Distinct`) and then map it cause it will reduce number of mapped items (i.e. can noticeably improve performance if number of filtered out items is big enough). But you should always check if it is so in your concrete use case.

Comment: @GuruStron Depending on what is in the collection that could have completely different results.

Comment: Depends on the type of `filterCollection`. if `filterCollection` items has multiple property and you are not selcting them all their are not equivalent . So none will be tter as it will be different result.

Comment: filterCollection is a list of int

Comment: Also the `Distinct` will only work if `FilterTable` overrides `Equals` and `GetHashCode` based on `FilterId`.  Otherwise it would use reference equality and nothing would be "distinct".  So if you're starting with a list of `int` you likely need to do the `Distinct` first.

Comment: "I am not sure this is correct." There are two different questions here: 1. is your appraoch **correct**, which means does it get its job *done*. 2. Is there any *better* (whatever that actually means) appraoch, that produces **the exact same result**. Please be more prcide on your actual question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. It depends on what is in `filterCollection`, if its Linq-To-Objects or Linq-To-Entities (database driven Linq provider) It depends on the implementation of `FilterTable`, because if this class does not override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` it will not work at all.

Since you project `filterId` i assume that the it's `IEnumerable<int>`(or string), then `Distinct` before the `Select` will work, it will remove duplicates. But after the `Select` it might not work because you create new `FilterTable` instances.

To make it work implement `IEquatable<FilterTable>` and override `Equals`+`GetHashCode`:

```
public class FilterTable : IEquatable<FilterTable>
{
    public int FilterId { get;set; }
    
    public bool Equals(FilterTable other)
    {
        return FilterId == other?.FilterId;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
         return obj is FilterTable ft && this.Equals(ft);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return FilterId.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```